# I'm trying to understand this for loop that's working with binary numbers

Tags: c#, for-loop, binary, bitwise-operators

Below, I have a for loop that I'm not sure I completely understand. This is how I thought it should've run:

It would look at 6 first and see that 6 & 1 (110 & 001) equals 0, not 1. So it should print out 6. It then performs 6>>1, moving on to 3. With 3, 011&001 equals 1 so it should end the for loop. However, when I run the for loop, it doesn't print anything at all. How am I thinking about this wrong?

```
for (int i = 6; (i & 1) == 1; i >>= 1)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Comment: I am interested to learn how people come to have false beliefs about programming languages. Can you describe how it is you came to the erroneous belief that a `for` loop condition must be false to run the body?

Comment: Honestly, your guess is as good as mine. I've never had that particular misconception as far as I can tell. It's possible I saw the == and immediately went to start looking for when it was equal to 1.

Comment: Your question is "how am I thinking about this wrong?" You claim to believe that the loop is entered when the condition is true, and claim to believe that `(6 & 1) == 1` is false, and you claim to believe that `(6&1)==1` is the loop condition, so I guess I cannot honestly tell you where your thinking went wrong. Plainly it did, but if you can't say more about what your thinking process was, I don't suppose anyone can tell you where it went wrong.

Comment: Correct. For some reason logic just left me when the condition was something other than (i < 100) or something of that nature. But you have cleared things up for me so thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How am I thinking about this wrong?

You have it *exactly backwards*. The loop condition must be *true* for the loop body to run, not *false*, as you believe.

Let's make that more crisp. If you have:

```
for (int i = initializer; condition ; increment)
  body
```

that is the same as

```
{
  int i = initializer;
  while (condition)
  {
    body;
    increment;
  }
}
```

(Well, *almost* the same. In a real `while` loop a `continue;` in `body` would start the loop over, but in a `for` loop the `continue` would go to `increment` in the code above.)

You understand that a `while` loop is like an `if`, right?  `if(condition) body` evaluates the condition, and if it is true then control passes to the body.  A `while` is just like an `if` except that it keeps on executing the `while` statement *until the condition is false*, not just once, like an `if`.

`for` loops are just fancy `while` loops. The body is entered if the condition is true.

In your example `(6 & 1) == 1` is false, so the loop body is never entered.  If you had started with `int i = 11` then `(11 & 1) == 1` would be true, the body would execute, then `i` would become `5`.  `(5 & 1) == 1` is true, so the loop executes again and `i` becomes `2`.  Since `(2 & 1) == 1` is false, the loop would not execute a third time.